# [Vue.js 2][vue-infinite-scroll] Why my Infinite Scroll doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, infinite-scroll

I would like to receive a boost as I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time. Thank you very much for your precious time.

**Goal :**

I would like to make an infinite scroll on the home page (home.vue), when the scroll reaches the bottom, the page will load x more jobs (20 for example). For that, I use the vue-infinite-scroll package.

**Results:**

I first divided the problem, I carried out tests on simple numbers, from 1 to 100, that I had put in the store, it worked! That is, it actually loaded me as many numbers as I had decided beforehand. Then I switched to my "JobCard" component (JobCard.vue), which I "multiplied" so that I could actually test it. And there, on the other hand, nothing. I'm stuck there.

**Errors:**

I have this error several times but I specify that the uniqueId is generated randomly on billions .. So very weird that it gives me errors like this .. I do not understand :

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'd52a4307a9c6dcf23250ee781a0b3c9f9134759a9dbe41186f'. This may cause an update error.
```

An example of my payload :

```
payload:[
    {
      companyPresentation:
        "Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.",
      title: "Sales",
      companyName: "Bnp",
      uniqueId: 9537799360154
    }]
```

[Here is a small screen showing the component..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYNLa.png)

**My code :**

home.vue :

```
<section
  v-infinite-scroll="loadMore"
  infinite-scroll-disabled="busy"
  infinite-scroll-distance="limit"
>
  <b-container class="pt-2">
    <h4>{{ $t("results") }}</h4>
    <div v-if="hasJobs">
      <transition-group name="fade">
        <JobCard
          class="line"
          v-for="job in filteredJobs"
          :key="job.uniqueId"
          :title="job.title"
          :companyPresentation="job.companyPresentation"
          :companyName="job.companyName"
        />
      </transition-group>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <b-card>{{ $t("noresults") }}</b-card>
    </div>
    <div v-if="filteredJobs.length === 0">
      <p>{{ $t("noresults") }} ¯\_(ツ)_/¯</p>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</section>
```

My function loadMore :

```
loadMore() {
  this.busy = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    const append = this.filteredJobs.slice(this.datas.length, this.datas.length + this.limit);
    this.datas = this.datas.concat(append);
    this.busy = false;
  }, 1000);
}
```

So, would you know where the problem is coming from? If you are missing anything, please let me know, thank you!

Comment: you're not modifying the `filteredJobs` array in `loadMore`. It seems that you need to switch `filteredJobs` and `datas` in that function.

Comment: Thanks @IgorMoraru ! It's it is resolved ! :)